# Retrieve a single item from DynamoDB using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I want to retrieve single item from DynamoDB but I'm unable to do that. I think I am missing something. I am able to scan the table using scan() function of boto but the fetching of a single item is not working. So it would be great if someone can tell me the correct way to do this.

**models.py** file:

```
import os
import boto
from boto import dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
from boto.dynamodb2.fields import HashKey, RangeKey, KeysOnlyIndex, GlobalAllIndex


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '****************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***************************'
REGION = 'us-east-1'
TABLE_NAME = 'Users'

conn = dynamodb2.connect_to_region(REGION, aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

table = Table(
    TABLE_NAME,
    connection=conn
)

results = table.scan()


for dynamo_item in results:
    print dict(dynamo_item.items())
```

I've tried using following:

```
results = table.scan(scan_filter={'email':'new'})
```

but got this error

> boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.UnknownFilterTypeError: Operator 'scan_filter' from 'scan_filter' is not recognized.

```
results = table.query_2(email = 'new')
```

> boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.UnknownFilterTypeError: Operator 'email' from 'email' is not recognized.

```
results = table.get_item(email='new')
```

> boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.ValidationException: ValidationException: 400 Bad Request
>   {u'message': u'The provided key element does not match the schema', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}

Comment: what is your table scheme? (hash/range key)

Comment: what is your hash key? (name/type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
results = table.query_2(email__eq = 'new')
```

You can also use the following:

```
__eq , __beginswith, __gte
```

Thanks to

@ing0: [dynamodb row count via python, boto query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968012/dynamodb-row-count-via-python-boto-query)

Source: *[DynamoDB2](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html)*

Answer (score -1):

If the table hash key is email then

`results = table.get_item(email='new')` should work.

Check if `email` is in type STRING (and not NUMBER) in the table scheme.

Comment: I've used this. You can look into my question. This command gives `boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.ValidationException: ValidationException: 400 Bad Request`

Comment: what is your email column type (as in dynamo db table)? maybe this is the reason.

Comment: You would write something like: `results = table.get_item(Key={'email': 'new'})`